# How can I add undo/redo functionalities in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm facing a problem with my HTML canvas project when I want to add undo/redo functionality, the idea is to merge this solution:
[How to display a Canvas in a Bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719260/how-to-display-a-canvas-in-a-bootstrap-modal)
with this one:
https://codepen.io/abidibo/pen/rmGBc

- this is my HTML code (bootstrap modal by the way)

```
<div id="bodyChartModal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myExtraLargeModalLabel">Extra Large</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="all-body-chart-buttons">
                    <div>
                        <button id="btnDraw" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        <button id="btnEraser" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-eraser" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button id="btnLargeWithLine" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        <button id="btnMediumWithLine" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size: 20px; color: black;"></i></button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button id="btnSmallWithLine" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size: 10px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        <button id="btnBlackColor" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-square" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button id="btnRedColor" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-square" style="font-size: 40px; color: #9f3631;"></i></button>
                        <button id="btnBlueColor" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-square" style="font-size: 40px; color: #00c1ca;"></i></button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button id="btnUndo" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-undo" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                        <button id="btnRedo" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-redo" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <button id="btnClear" class="btn" style="width: 80px; height: 70px;"><i class="fas fa-times" style="font-size: 40px; color: black;"></i></button>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="canvas-box">
                    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="750" height="480" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="flaticon-cancel-12"></i> Discard</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- this is my CSS code

```
#myCanvas{
    background: transparent;
}

.canvas-box {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("/images/body-chart-image.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

.all-body-chart-buttons{
    float: left;
}
```

- And this is my Javascript code

```
<script>
        class Signature {
            constructor() {
                this.redo_list = [];
                this.undo_list = [];
                this.img = new Image();
                this.eraser = false;
                this.color = "#000000";
                this.sign = false;
                this.begin_sign = false;
                this.width_line = 5;
                this.canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                this.offsetLeft = this.canvas.offsetLeft;
                this.offsetTop = this.canvas.offsetTop;
                this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
                this.context.lineJoin = 'round';
                this.context.lineCap = 'round';
                this.whenMouseDown();
                this.whenMouseUp();
                this.whenMouseMove();
                this.createSignature();
                this.clearCanvas();
                this.resetCanvas();
                this.changeColorToRed();
                this.changeColorToBlack();
                this.changeColorToBlue();
                this.changeWithLineToSmall();
                this.changeWithLineToMedium();
                this.changeWithLineToLarge();
                this.erase();
                this.draw();
                this.undo();
                this.redo();
                this.undoEvent();
                this.redoEvent();
            }

            updateMousePosition(mX, mY) {
                let rect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                let scaleX = this.canvas.width / rect.width;
                let scaleY = this.canvas.height / rect.height;
                this.cursorX = (mX - rect.left) * scaleX;
                this.cursorY = (mY - rect.top) * scaleY;
            }

            whenMouseDown() {
                document.addEventListener("mousedown", ({
                                                            pageX,
                                                            pageY
                                                        }) => {
                    this.sign = true;
                    this.updateMousePosition(pageX, pageY);
                    this.context.beginPath();
                    this.context.moveTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
                    this.context.lineTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
                    this.context.strokeStyle = this.color;
                    this.context.lineWidth = this.width_line;
                    this.context.stroke();
                })
            }

            whenMouseUp() {
                document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
                    this.sign = false;
                    this.begin_sign = false;
                })
            }

            whenMouseMove() {
                this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ({
                                                               pageX,
                                                               pageY
                                                           }) => {
                    if (this.sign) {
                        this.updateMousePosition(pageX, pageY);
                        this.createSignature();
                    }
                })
            }

            createSignature() {
                if (this.erazer){
                    this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
                }
                else{
                    this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                }
                if (!this.begin_sign) {
                    this.context.beginPath();
                    this.context.moveTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
                    this.redo_list = [];
                    this.undo_list.push(this.canvas.toDataURL());
                    this.begin_sign = true;
                } else {
                    this.context.lineTo(this.cursorX, this.cursorY);
                    this.context.strokeStyle = this.color;
                    this.context.lineWidth = this.width_line;
                    this.context.stroke();
                }
            }

            clearCanvas() {
                this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            }

            changeColorToRed() {
                document.getElementById("btnRedColor").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.color = "#9f3631";
                })
            }

            changeColorToBlack() {
                document.getElementById("btnBlackColor").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.color = "#000000";
                })
            }

            changeColorToBlue() {
                document.getElementById("btnBlueColor").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.color = "#00c1ca";
                })
            }

            changeWithLineToSmall(){
                document.getElementById("btnSmallWithLine").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.width_line = 5;
                })
            }

            changeWithLineToMedium(){
                document.getElementById("btnMediumWithLine").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.width_line = 10;
                })
            }

            changeWithLineToLarge(){
                document.getElementById("btnLargeWithLine").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.width_line = 20;
                })
            }

            erase(){
                document.getElementById("btnEraser").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.erazer = true;
                })
            }

            draw(){
                document.getElementById("btnDraw").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.erazer = false;
                    this.width_line = 5;
                })
            }

            resetCanvas() {
                document.getElementById("btnClear").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
                    this.erazer = false;
                    this.clearCanvas();
                })
            }

            undo(){
                if (this.undo_list.length){
                    this.redo_list.push(this.canvas.toDataURL());
                    var restore_state = this.undo_list;
                    var img = this.img.src = restore_state;
                    var width = this.canvas.width;
                    var height = this.canvas.height;
                    img.onload = function() {
                        document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                        document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
                    }
                }
            }

            redo(){
                if(this.redo_list.length){
                    this.undo_list.push(this.canvas.toDataURL());
                    var restore_state = this.redo_list;
                    var img = this.img.src = restore_state;
                    var width = this.canvas.width;
                    var height = this.canvas.height;
                    img.onload = function() {
                        document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                        document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
                    }
                }
            }

            undoEvent() {
                document.getElementById("btnUndo").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.undo();
                })
            }

            redoEvent() {
                document.getElementById("btnRedo").addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.redo();
                })
            }

        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
            new Signature();
        });
    </script>
```

> **All the functionalities working fine except undo and redo**

[image]

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser's dev tools console? For example, it looks as though this.undo_list is an array but you are treating it as an img src in undo().

Comment: the same code works fine here https://codepen.io/abidibo/pen/rmGBc

Comment: Hi, the code in the pen looks rather different to me. It's popping off the list to get the restore state and then from that it's taking the src.

Comment: Oh My goood, Thank u so much ^^ U saved my day.